# Solving a limit using Maclaurin series $ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{xe^{2x}+xe^{-2x}-4x^{3}-2x}{\sin^{2}x-x^{2}} $

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I need to find the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{xe^{2x}+xe^{-2x}-4x^{3}-2x}{\sin^{2}x-x^{2}}
$$
using Maclaurin series. I don't know to what degree am I supposed to develop each expression.

I think $\sin x$ in the denominator must be expanded to at least order $3$, but what about the numerator?

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You would go up to the next nonzero order. For example, in the numerator this would be $4$, but the expression on the left is an odd function so there will be no degree $4$ term - you will have to go to degree $5$. In the denominator like you said you would have to go to $3$, but the expression on the left is this time an even function, so a degree $3$ term would not exist you would have to go one further.

Comment: Hint: your expression may be written $$
 - 4x\frac{{\cosh (2x) - \left( {1 + \frac{{(2x)^2 }}{2}} \right)}}{{\cos (2x) - \left( {1 - \frac{{(2x)^2 }}{2}} \right)}}.
$$ Do you know the Maclaurin series of $\cos$ and $\cosh$?

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I went through the following procedure and arrived at a limit of $0$:

The [Maclaurin Series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) of $\cos(2x)$ is $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-4)^k x^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}$, which you may verify for example using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maclaurin%20series%20cos%282x%29) by entering the command `maclaurin series cos(2x)`. The Maclaurin Series of $\cosh(2x)$ is $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{4^k x^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}$, which you may verify [there](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maclaurin%20series%20cosh%282x%29) (as well) by entering the command `maclaurin series cosh(2x)`.

Gary's hint is the key, since you may rewrite your limit now as:

$$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}-4 x\frac{\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{4^k x^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}-\left(1+\frac{1}{2} (2 x)^2\right)}{\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-4)^k x^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}-\left(1-\frac{1}{2} (2 x)^2\right)}$$

Your limit becomes zero, because both Maclaurin Series converge towards $1$ for $x\rightarrow0$:

- $\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{4^k x^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}\right)=1$, the Maclaurin Series expansion at $x=0$ is $1+2x^2+\frac{2}{3}x^4+\ldots$ (see details including a plot [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BSum%5B%284%29%5Ek*x%5E%282%20k%29%2FFactorial%5B2%20k%5D%2C%20%7Bk%2C%200%2C%20Infinity%7D%5D%2C%20x%20-%3E%200%5D))
- $\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-4)^k x^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}\right)=1$, the Maclaurin Series expansion at $x=0$ is $1-2x^2+\frac{2}{3}x^4-\ldots$ (see details and a plot [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BSum%5B%28-4%29%5Ek*x%5E%282%20k%29%2FFactorial%5B2%20k%5D%2C%20%7Bk%2C%200%2C%20Infinity%7D%5D%2C%20x%20-%3E%200%5D))

Your expression can be finally simplified to:

$$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}-4 x\frac{1-\left(1+\frac{1}{2} (2 x)^2\right)}{1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2} (2 x)^2\right)}=\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}4 x=0$$